# pipe an awk object created with awk code

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to know if there is a method for creating awk objects inside an awk call. I need to build a key/value map and use it in an awk call. More in details, I have a map linking some labels with a unique id (e.g. "ID1002", "External compartment"). I would like to use this map to identify a set of unique ids from another table. Here is what I was thinking about:

```
awk 'BEGIN{map=system(awk '{m[$1]=$2}' first.csv)}{print map[$1]}' second.csv
```

Obviously this doesn't work and I was wondering how can I do something like that without building an awk script.

Comment: Just do it in one call to awk instead of two. Use `NR==FNR` to select only the first file/etc.

Comment: System returns the return code, not a string., although even if it did the command makes no sense as it doesn't print anything.

Comment: This is an example of the XY Problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us **what** you want to do, not **how** you you want to do it, and include sample input and expected output and we can show you the right approach. I can't imagine what you mean when you say you want to write an awk script `without building an awk script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way this done in awk is:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{m[$1]=$2;next}{print m[$1]}' first.csv second.csv
```

**Explanation**:

- `NR` is a special variable that gets incremented on each record read
- `FNR` is similar to `NR` however it is reset for each new file read
- `next` instructs awk to stop executing for the current record and get the next record.

With the definitions set you can read the script as:

```
NR==FNR         # Conditional that is only true when reading the first file
{m[$1]=$2;next} # Create a map and move on to the next line
{print m[$1]}   # Using next in the first block means this only runs on the second file
```

Comment: Brilliant! It worked! Thank you very very very much. I didn't know the ```NR==FNR``` trick!